# How to modify null value/two double quotes that contain nothing in xml with Powershell?

Tags: xml, powershell, web-config

I need to modify web.config file which I am reading as xml and the line i need to change is this:

```
<add key="My.Unique.Repository" value="" />
```

as you can see, there is nothing in value=" " just the double quotes.

I have no script written for this, I am trying to find out how to do it in the simplest way before I attempt to compile code

P.S. I have zero powershell experience, kindly respond in simple terms, thank you

Comment: What you want to change in the XML ? are you trying to create this section in XML ?

Comment: I want to change: 
<add key="My.Unique.Repository" value="" />
to
<add key="My.Unique.Repository" value="some_text_here" />

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer that I needed, see the code below.
Thanks Theo for providing me with this answer.
https://stackoverflow.com/users/9898643/theo

```
$path        = '\\lonngp-ap\c$\Program Files\AIR\IIS\web2.config'
[xml]$config = Get-Content -Path $path -Raw
$stuffIwant  = "\\StringServer123"
$config.SelectNodes("//add[@key='My.Unique.Repository']") | ForEach-Object { $_.SetAttribute("value", $stuffIwant) }
$config.Save($path)
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably something along the lines of

```
    $xml = [xml]'<add key="My.Unique.Repository" value="" />'

    $target = $xml.SelectSingleNode("/add")
    $target.SetAttribute("value", "some value");
```

Comment: I tried this but got this error: Method invocation failed because [System.Xml.XmlDocument] does not contain a method named 'SetAttribute'.

Comment: I don't know why you get that; make sure you load your xml properly; see edit.